# ASCII screensaver application for terminal

Tags: terminal, ascii-art

Does anybody know of a terminal application that acts as a sort of screen saver and reads from a text file after inactivity/a command is run and displays it on the screen? I don’t use my machine directly much, and usually SSH into it so I’d like it to look nice in my room with some ASCII art rather than just sitting there looking bland. There’s a bunch [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/699579/ascii-screensaver-for-the-command-line-or-a-tui) but they don’t seem to be very customisable and I’d like to put my own files on the screen.

Comment: There are several nonsense generators to mimick heavy work, like this one https://github.com/svenstaro/genact.

Comment: Look at this https://gitlab.com/mezantrop/ascsaver